# How to make a phone call programatically without Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new on android and i want make phone call without use the `intent`.

I know that this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Can i make call in android programmatically without use "`Intent`"?

Do you have any answer?

Thanks

Comment: You want to execute an action, this is done via intent. Thats the normal and supposed way. The question is, why you need to do it without using intent?

Comment: in my app i want make call that the user can't understand phone calling..

Comment: pardon me, but thats hard to understand. The user shouldnt see that there is a phone call ongoing?

Comment: it's not ongoing, but i want when my app is run calling to another phone...

Comment: This is not allowed, because that would let people create malicious apps dialling expensive phone numbers without the user knowing. @CommonsWare's answer is the correct one, and you should accept it.

Comment: You can run a call directly, but user always will have the "call" view

Answer (score 2):

> Can i make call in android programmatically without use "Intent"?

Not from an ordinary Android SDK app. A custom ROM mod certainly could.

Comment: Dear CommonsWare, why you give me a minus??I'm new android developer:(

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and that's a security feature.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL

Comment: Dear Arve, why you give me a minus??I'm new android developer:(

Comment: @saber I did not give you a minus. Someone else probably thought you should have done more research.

Comment: @saber and on a side note, I really recommend this Android course if you're a beginner: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853 :-)

Comment: thanks Arve, please give me plus.. i need it to ask my question :(

Comment: @saber please read up on http://stackoverflow.com/tour and sources you reach from there, and learn how StackOverflow works.