# How can I create Outgoing call handling dialer in android?

Tags: android, phone-call, android-dialer

I want to create Phone dialer in android .
Purpose is handling out going call event .

I have found many dialer in android but no one is working like this.For dialing purpose they are sending event to native android dialer . I want to make call through my dialer and disconnect with it also .

Please any one having any idea about it ,please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a phone call programatically without Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242909/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programatically-without-intent)

Comment: I used these guide but not going to work http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html